# QGIS raster fill color change

Tags: qgis, raster, color

How I can change the color of a Raster fill in QGIS? I need to change it from black original to a RGB green code.[image]

Comment: Aren't these the properties of the vector layer in the screenshot?

Comment: Lesson: Changing Raster Symbology https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html

Comment: It is not the same type of layer. I have a traditional poligon layer, where I want to fill it with a raster picture. But this picture I use to fill poligonal layer need to change color.

Comment: I believe that you must find the image file and edit the colors with Gimp or similar software.